# what is the characterization of mutant bacteria and how is it done?

Tags: microbiology

I have a task to characterize protease producing bacterial mutants but I have failed to understand what it is and how it is done

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the biology stack.  This is clearly a homework question.  While those are okay, they have to follow [the guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for homework questions.  Please [edit] to show what you've tried, and where the confusion specifically lies.  Thank you!